# AWS CodeStar - AWS Elastic Beanstalk vs Amazon EC2

Tags: java, spring-mvc, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-codestar

I want to create a Spring Boot application but I am not sure about the difference with the 2 options available anf which one I should choose

[image]

Comment: I suggest if you're unsure you should start with Beanstalk. In this case amazon will take care of running the machine, OS and JVM for you. If you go for EC2 you'll have to take care of e everything your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EC2 is nothing but a plain instance, where you must take care of installing required softwares such as databases along with that we must tell when the system should be scaled up and when it should be scaled down. But BeanStalk is automated version of EC2 where itself takes care of all the administrative tasks such as scaling up and down and you are charged only for the resources you used like SNS , RDS etc.

Simply put :
**EC2 is Iaas & BeanStalk is Paas**